# define hash cod SHA256 NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sha256, sha

How to select the hash code on NodeJS?

I have a system made in another language with passwords on SHA256

The function there is:

```
#define HASH_CODE = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';
SHA256_PassHash(HASH_CODE, password, 64);
```

First, param is the hash code, second is the var will be encrypted, third is the base64

I made the encrypt on NodeJS, but I have no control on hash code, so the systems don't make the same hash, how to select the code on the register on NodeJS so the system communicates with others?

```
const code = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';
const normal = 'anne';
const crypto = require('crypto');
const encrypted = crypto
     .createHash('sha256')
     .update(normal)
     .digest('base64');
console.log(encrypted);
```

A exemple of compatibly code, this login on PHP
login.php

```
<?php require_once('../mysql_conn.php'); ?> 
    <?php
    session_start();
    $HASH_SENHA = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';

    if(isset($_SESSION['Username']))
    {
        header("location: ../myaccount.php");
        exit();
    } 
    if(isset($_POST['usr']) && isset($_POST['psw']) && isset($_POST['botao'])) 
    { 
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($MYSQL_CONNECT, $_POST['usr']);  
        $senha = strtoupper(hash("sha256", $_POST['psw'] . $HASH_SENHA));  
        $query = mysqli_query($MYSQL_CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username='$usuario' AND Senha='$senha' LIMIT 1");  

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1)  
        {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert('Incorrect Username or Password.');
                        window.location = '../login.php';
                  </script>";
            exit();
        }
        else 
        {
            //login efetuado 
            $dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);  


            if (isset($_SESSION['loc'])) {
                header("location:".$_SESSION['loc']);
            }
            else header("location:../index.php");

        }  
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to provide the result from both Node and Other hash

Comment: Which is the other language the `SHA256_PassHash` is being called from?

Comment: password 123 there (with code ):
8A8E0E514F3A1F3D160C58C99BC66C81A10256E6A3462002A53ADACAD6C43EAB

password 123 in Node (with no code control):
kLjeQFHwK3opSENB86kD4bLGojP1Rl4ZxjRTXHsxXm8=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the PHP code you've provided.

```
hash("sha256", $_POST['psw'] . $HASH_SENHA)
```

It's hashing the string concatenation of `$_POST['psw']` and `$HASH_SENHA`

So, the equivalent code in Node.js should look like below

**Node.js**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const code = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';
const input = 'password 123';

const encrypted = crypto
     .createHash('sha256')
     .update(input + code)  // concatenation
     .digest('hex');        // get hash in hex format

console.log(encrypted);
```

**Output**

```
3b3107f01da624da6bb014abe532aa7416869811ebe321784b26770cd2dd74ff
```